# Laravel Service provider not working

Tags: php, laravel

I've bind my interface called `CustomerRepository` to `EloquentCustomerRepository`. This is my `CustomerServiceProvider`:

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(CustomerRepository::class,EloquentCustomerRepository::class);
        $this->app->bind(PackageRepository::class,EloquentPackageRepository::class);
    }
```

When I try to instantiate it in my controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\api\v1;

use Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\customer\CustomerRepository;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Lsupport\customer\Customer;
use App\Http\Requests;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    protected $CustomerRepository;

    public function __construct(CustomerRepository $CustomerRepository)
    {
        $this->CustomerRepository = $CustomerRepository;
    }
```

It throws the following error:

> Target [Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\Customer\CustomerRepository] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\api\v1\CustomerController].

I also registered it in `app.config`:

```
App\Providers\CustomerServiceProvider::class,
```

What am I doing wrong?

**CustomerServiceProvider**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\customer\EloquentCustomerRepository;
use Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\customer\EloquentPackageRepository;
use Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\customer\CustomerRepository;
use Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\customer\PackageRepository;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CustomerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(CustomerRepository::class,EloquentCustomerRepository::class);
        $this->app->bind(PackageRepository::class,EloquentPackageRepository::class);
    }
}
```

**CustomerRepository**

```
    <?php

    namespace Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\Customer;

    interface CustomerRepository
    {
        public function create($request);
    }

**EloquentCustomerRepository**

<?php

namespace Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\customer;

use Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\customer\CusteromRepositoryTrait;
use Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\remain\RightTrait;
use Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\remain\JsonTrait;
use Lsupport\customer\Customer;

class EloquentCustomerRepository implements CustomerRepository
{
    use JsonTrait;
    use RightTrait;
    use CustomerRepositoryTrait;

    code.....
```

Comment: My understanding is that bind()'s second argument should be a closure `https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#binding`

Comment: Try using `$this->app->bind('CustomerRepository', 'EloquentCustomerRepository');`. If you use `EloquentCustomerRepository` instead of `CustomerRepository`, on the controller, does that work?

Comment: @milz Yes! when I use EloquentCustomerRepository it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might need to use the `->bind()` with strings where the strings are the names of the classes including the namespaces. Please post the entire code of `CustomerServiceProvider`, `CustomerRepository` and `EloquentCustomerRepository` (or, at least, the declarations). Thanks

Comment: @milz please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the first thing I notice is that you probably want the same namespaces on the interface and on the class. So, the namespace of `EloquentCustomerRepository` should be

```
namespace Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\Customer;
```

and not

```
namespace Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\customer;
```

(with lower customer).

Now, on your `CustomerServiceProvider`, you should use:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\Customer\CustomerRepository', 'Lsupport\repositories\api\v1\Customer\EloquentCustomerRepository');
}
```

Make sure you run `composer dumpautoload -o` on the command line.